# How to export all Issues and its contents (Full content) to excel in JIRA?

Tags: jira

Here I can able to download only the fields / I can get the contents of only one particular issues to word.

JIRA : Using Latest version.

Logged in as Administrator.

I searched Google but could'nt find.

Comment: Note that using JIRA Cloud, you can only export 1000 issues at a time.  There are work-arounds, but I have had mixed results.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Go to `Issues` and make a filter that returns all the issues you want
2. In the top right corner, there is a `Views` menu item. Open it.
3. Select the `Excel (all fields)` option to export all issues to Excel

Comment: In View : see - Full Content, its displaying the issues very clear. i want it like that. Is that possible to get it. May be in Word/Excel, no problem.

Comment: Just one comment: you will loose the comments to all issues, and the attachments as well.

Comment: Also the file is not Excel but HTML with an XLS extension.  It can be cleaned up and saved as a CSV.

Comment: But while importing it showing no row under **Map fields-csv** field, Is there anything related Delimiter char related issue, i have tried with these 3 **, "  ' ** but nothing working. And since there is no direct option for cvs export, so I export excel and Export cvs from excel. Any suggestion !

Comment: You can export as `Word` for full version with comments like the `Full Content` view

Comment: The button cannot be found anymore :(

Answer (score 4):

@user1747116 you can use the method described by Whim but you do not get all of the information out of an issue.

You do have a couple of options:

1. If you are versed in XML you can go to System->Import / Export Section -> Backup and it does a full backup of your JIRA instance in XML as described in this [help post](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Exporting+issues).
2. You can use the method described by Whim of simply going to the issues list and clicking on the 'export function', but ALSO before doing that using one of the add-ons that allows you to export comments as well. Plug-ins specifically mentioned in this [help article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/How+to+add+comments+to+Excel+export) are "[All Comments](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/it.skyit.jira.plugins.all-comments-cf)", "[JIRA Utilities](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.jira.utils.customware-jira-utilities)", and "[Last Comment](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.capitalcityconsultants.jira.plugins.customfields.ccc-lastcomment)".
3. Write a Crystal Report formatted in a way to export into Excel. We have done this to make the information both accessible to those not versed in SQL. We have in particular done this for
4. You write an SQL Query and go directly at the database, and saving to CSV. *Note in JIRA 4 to 6 the schema changed and we had to redo several of our queries so keep this in mind. But this is one to get you started in JIRA 6. Note time log is in ([worklog] and File Attachments are in ([fileattachment]) and comments are in ([jiraaction]). Each of these tend to have multiple entries per issue so you will need to do further joins to get them all into the same query. This is also useful know how if you are doing it in a Crystal Report and then exporting to excel.*

```html
SELECT TOP 1000 _JI.ID
      ,_JI.pkey
      ,_JI.PROJECT
      ,_PRJ.pname
   ,_JI.REPORTER
      ,_JI.ASSIGNEE
      ,_JI.issuetype
   ,_IT.pname
      ,_JI.SUMMARY
      ,_JI.DESCRIPTION
      ,_JI.ENVIRONMENT
      ,_JI.PRIORITY
   ,_PRI.pname
      ,_JI.RESOLUTION
   ,_RES.pname
      ,_JI.issuestatus
   ,_IS.Pname
      ,_JI.CREATED
      ,_JI.UPDATED
      ,_JI.DUEDATE
      ,_JI.RESOLUTIONDATE
      ,_JI.VOTES
      ,_JI.WATCHES
      ,_JI.TIMEORIGINALESTIMATE
      ,_JI.TIMEESTIMATE
      ,_JI.TIMESPENT
      ,_JI.WORKFLOW_ID
      ,_JI.SECURITY
      ,_JI.FIXFOR
      ,_JI.COMPONENT
      ,_JI.issuenum
      ,_JI.CREATOR
     FROM jiraissue _JI (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN PROJECT _PRJ ON _JI.Project = _PRJ.ID
     LEFT JOIN ISSUESTATUS _IS ON _JI.issuestatus = _IS.ID
  LEFT JOIN ISSUETYPE _IT ON _JI.issuetype = _IT.ID
  LEFT JOIN PRIORITY _PRI ON _JI.Priority = _PRI.ID
  LEFT JOIN RESOLUTION _RES ON _JI.Resolution = _RES.ID
```

*Note: You could get rid of the redundant fields, but I left both in so you can see where they came from. You can also put a where clause for a single issue ID or limit the outputs to a particular project. The top 1000 only displays the first 1000 results. Remove that if you are comfortable with it returning everything. (We tens of thousands in our db so I put that in there).*

Answer (score 3):

Exporting **all** details to Excel using the built-in export feature is simply impossible. Excel export will not export you the comments, the attachment, change history, etc. As other answers mention the Excel output produced by JIRA is in fact an HTML file, which works in many situations, but doesn't if you need precise representation of data.

Our company built a commercial add-on called the [Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel), which generates native Excel exports (in XLSX format) from JIRA data.

It is powerful alternative to the built-in feature, with [major advantages](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin#comparison) and [awesome customization](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/customization). It really supports Excel analysis functionality, including formulas, charts, pivot tables- and pivot charts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution.

I downloaded the file like this:

- "Issues" > "Search for Issues"
- "Export" button > "Excel (HTML, All Fields)"

After downloading the file, Excel (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013) was not opening the download Jira.xls file for me.

I worked around that by doing the following:

- Change the ".xls" to ".html"
- Open the new "Jira.html" file in Chrome
- Highlight/Select the table contents of the exported Jira Issues
- Copy and then paste into a new excel file

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **Better Excel** add-on is great (we use it) but it cannot do attachments (AFAIK). Another add-on, **JExcel Pro**,  can.